# ESlint (airbnb) and no lone blocks

Tags: vue.js, ecmascript-6, eslint, eslint-config-airbnb

I have a method in my vue js app.

```
 resetFilter: function() {
             $('.person').fadeIn(500);
             this.toggleDepartments;

           },
```

**The error is "Block is redundant: no lone blocks:**

How do I rewrite this in ES6 to fix the linting error?

Comment: this line `this.toggleDepartments` does nothing, did you miss some call() parenthesis ?

Comment: No that's not it but thanks for your reply as it did get me to the right answer. A large block of the code is wrapped in  { } brackets to solve a scope issue.

Comment: @BiAiB is say (as well as the error) `this.toggleDepartments;` line is redundant, it will do nothing unless it's a computed prop... is it?

Comment: A get accessor should not have a side effect, it is very confusing.